# Convert string enclosed in %% to lower case in python

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe in which one of the fields has values enclosed within %%..%%. The contents enclosed are not consisted in terms of case. I want to convert them into lower case.

Below is a snapshot of the dataframe.[image]

The text in the column looks like this

```
https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/Activities|http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/things-to-do/search?location=%%t.Trip_Intrip_1_dest_City_1%%

https://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/expus/email/2016/us/banner/images/image_stor-34461_09_600x250.jpg|%%mis_lx_Offers_mod_Images.LargeImageURL%%
```

I want to convert the above text to the following format:

```
https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/Activities|http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/things-to-do/search?location=%%t.trip_intrip_1_dest_city_1%%

https://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/expus/email/2016/us/banner/images/image_stor-34461_09_600x250.jpg|%%mis_lx_offers_mod_images.largeimageurl%%
```

Only the string enclosed with %% are to be convert to lowercase

Comment: The text `LargeImageUrl` is still not all lower caps in your question

Comment: Can't you not map it and do a `.split("%%")` then `.lower()`?

Comment: @theBrainyGeekSorry, that was a typo. Made the change. Thanks.

Comment: @16num I don't want to split the content in the column. If i split it then i will have to put them back together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since strings are immutable in Python, you will have to reassign the new value. Therefore, I think, you will be better off just iterating through the string (since in comments you say you want to avoid `split`).
I was thinking something like this

```
new=''
f=0
for i in textstr:
    if i == '%':
        f += 1
    if (f/2)%2 == 1:
        new+=i.lower()
    else:
        new+=i
```

Or go with regex

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regular expression:

- Find all sequences to be replaced
- Replace each sequence with its lowercase equivalent

---

```
import re

link1 = 'https://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/expus/email/2016/us/banner/images/image_stor-34461_09_600x250.jpg|%%mis_lx_Offers_mod_Images.LargeImageURL%%'
link2 = 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/Activities|http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/things-to-do/search?location=%%t.Trip_Intrip_1_dest_City_1%%'
links = [link1, link2]

for idx, link in enumerate(links):
    lowers = re.findall(r'%%.*?%%', link)
    for x in lowers:
        links[idx] = re.sub(r'%%.*?%%', x.lower(), link)

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

---

output:

```
https://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/expus/email/2016/us/banner/images/image_stor-34461_09_600x250.jpg|%%mis_lx_offers_mod_images.largeimageurl%%
https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/Activities|http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/things-to-do/search?location=%%t.trip_intrip_1_dest_city_1%%
```

Comment: thanks. I tried your approach and its working if there is only 1 %% enclosed string. But if there are 2 like say `%%mis_lx_Offers_mod_Images.LargeImageURL%%|https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/Activities|http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/things-to-do/search?location=%%t.Trip_Intrip_1_dest_City_1%%` It repeats the last value in the loop. Output becomes: `|%%t.trip_intrip_1_dest_city_1%%|https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/Activities|http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.nz/things-to-do/search?location=%%t.trip_intrip_1_dest_city_1%%`

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex suggested by @mentalita

input_df:

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----+---------------------------------+
|col1|col2                             |
+----+---------------------------------+
|1   |http://%%FOO%%|some_string%%BAR%%|
|2   |http://%%FOO%%|some_string       |
+----+---------------------------------+
```

code:

```
def convert_to_lower(link):
    target_strings = re.findall(r'%%.*?%%', link)
    for x in target_strings:
            link = re.sub(x, x.lower(), link)
    return link

convert_to_lower_udf = F.udf(lambda x: convert_to_lower(x))
df = df\
    .withColumn('converted_strings', convert_to_lower_udf('col2'))
```

output_df:

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|col1|col2                             |converted_strings                |
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|1   |http://%%FOO%%|some_string%%BAR%%|http://%%foo%%|some_string%%bar%%|
|2   |http://%%FOO%%|some_string       |http://%%foo%%|some_string       |
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```